# Generate 2 arrays from an array

Tags: php

i have an array like this, with x-coordinate and y-coordinate forming an individual entry.

```
$polygon = array("10 0", "20 5", "15 15", "22 15");
```

Now how can i break this array into 2 different arrays, such that all x-coordinates will fall into one array and all y-coordinates will fall into another array, like this:

```
$x = array(10, 20, 15, 22);
$y = array(0, 5, 15, 15);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$x = $y = array();
$polygon = array("10 0", "20 5", "15 15", "22 15");
foreach ($polygon as $coor) {
    list($x[], $y[]) = explode(' ', $coor);
}
```

This will do the trick :)

And to combine them back:

```
//assuming that $x and $y have the same number of items
for ($i = 0; $i<count($x); $i++) {
    $polygon[] = $x[$i] .' ' . $y[$i];
}
```

Comment: Nice use of list() there, didn't know that was possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just curious to know, how to do the reverse of it? I mean, if i have the $x and $y arrays, how to generate $polygon array?

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
$x = array();
$y = array();
foreach($polygon as $entry){
 $splitted = explode(" ", $entry);
 //append x and y 
 $x[] = $splitted[0];
 $y[] = $splitted[1];
}
```